# How to return File downloaded as DataBuffer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am downloading a file like below:

```
private File downloadAndReturnFile(String fileId, String destination) {
    log.info("Downloading file.. " + fileId);
    Path path = Paths.get(destination);
    Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer = webClient.get().uri("/the/download/uri/" + fileId + "").retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
            .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("{}", fileId + " - File downloaded successfully"));
    
    //DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE).share().block();
    
    return ???? // What should I do here to return above DataBuffer as file? 
}
```

How can I return the dataBuffer as a File? Or, how can I convert this dataBuffer to a File object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`DataBufferUtils.write` method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBufferUtils.html#write-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel-long-). To do that, you should

1. instantiate a `File` object (maybe using `fileId` and `destination`) which is also the return value you want
2. create `OutputStream` or `Path` or `Channel`s object from the `File` object
3. call `DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, ....).share().block()` to write the `DataBuffer` into the file

viz. (all thrown exceptions are omitted),

```java
...
File file = new File(destination, fileId);
Path path = file.toPath();
DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE).share().block();
return file;
```

Or,

```java
...
Path path = Paths.get(destination);
DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE).share().block();
return path.toFile();
```

Comment: Can you please put pseudo code for it? Sorry for being dumb.

Comment: Would you mind to provide the real value of `destination` variable and the download uri path? I can download to a file using the code.

Comment: this is what I have as destination (String) - `c:/aap/test01.pdf`. My orginal question's commented line writes to file without any issue.

Comment: To retrieve `File` object from `Path` object, you could simply use `Path.toFile()` method. If your original code successfully writes contents to the file, you can `return path.toFile();`. I'm sorry for I'm not in the Windows environment, so I am not sure whether to create a `File` object Windows environment is different from the Linux.

Comment: Ahh.. my bad. I created a copy of the method and was still calling a wrong method. Its working as expected. Can say enough thanks @Tonny. Accepting it with a big smile. !

Answer (score 0):

In case someone looking for a full code. Just sharing Tonny's solution to the fullest.

```
private File downloadAndReturnFile(String fileId, String destination) throws FileNotFoundException {
            log.info("Downloading file.. " + fileId);
            Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer = webClient.get().uri("/the/download/uri/" + fileId + "").retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
                    .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("{}", fileId + " - File downloaded successfully"));
            Path path = Paths.get(destination);
            DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE).share().block();
            return path.toFile();
        }
```